# ngClass methord is not applyed to the dom element

Tags: angular, ng-class

I am trying to implement ngClass methods to the dom element but I m facing some problem in implementing it and style is not applied to the dom element

component code ->

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-imp-style',
  templateUrl: './imp-style.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./imp-style.component.css']
})
export class ImpStyleComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor() { }


  getcssClass(flag: string) {
    let cssclas;
    if (flag === 'night') {
      cssclas = { 'one': true,   'two': false,
    }; } else {
       cssclas = {'two': true, 'one': false,
      }; }
  }
  ngOnInit() {
 }
}
```

HTMl CODE

```
<div [ngClass]="getcssClass('night')"> hello world </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to return cssclas
now code is working

```
getcssClass(flag: string) {
    let cssclas;
    if (flag === 'night') {
      cssclas = { 'one': true,   'two': false,
    }; } else {
       cssclas = {'two': true, 'one': false,
      }; }

return cssclas;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is at your function:

```
getcssClass(flag: string) {
    let cssclas;
    if (flag === 'night') {
      cssclas = { 'one': true,   'two': false,
    }; } else {
       cssclas = {'two': true, 'one': false,
      }; }
  }
```

should return the cssclas you are asssigning